# How to get the LIs seperate from the UL in Selenium

Tags: java, html, list, selenium, html-lists

I am trying to filter through a list and click on the correct text.

The list is size 2 and looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>first</span></li>
  <li><span>second</span></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason my code is giving me back the entire UL instead of individual entries and doesn't iterate across the internal elements.

```
public void clickRightThing(String name) {      
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.className("ul-classname"));

    String returnedName;

    for (WebElement row : list) {
        returnedName = row.getText();   
        System.out.println(returnedName);
        System.out.println(returnedName.length());

        if (returnedName.equals(name)) {
            row.click();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Running clickRightThing("first)" will print out the names of the rows in only one run of the loop, size 11 which is length of first + second, and finally, size of list 1. It never enters the if statement since the string being returned is both rows and not the first.

```
first 
second 
11 
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your selector, it looks like you are selecting the `ul` element: `ul-classname`. This is a good first step, and the next is to select all child `li` elements of the `ul`:

```
// Select the parent UL
WebElement parentUL = driver.findElement(By.className("ul-classname"));

// Get all WebElements of type "li" that are children of parentUL
List<WebElement> childLIs = parentUL.findElement(By.tagName("li"));
...
```